# Redeclare function type hints inside child classes without redeclaring functions

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a Superclass that a few subclasses inherit from.
The functions in these subclasses are identical to that in the superclass, so there is no reason for me to redeclare them, however the parameter types of these functions are different in my childclasses.

Is there a way to include updated typehints for the functions from the superclass, without having to fully redeclare them, inside of the childclasses?